# Moving data from Arduino internal serial buffer into memory

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino, buffer

The first section of [this](http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/reading-serial-on-the-arduino) tutorial explains how to read from the serial port of an Arduino if you know how many characters you are receiving.

The code is something like this:

```
byte buffer = 0; 

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop(){
if (Serial.available() >= 8) { //wait for the internal serial buffer to have all 8 characters in it
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    buffer[i] = Serial.read(); //move from internal buffer into memory
  }
}
```

The part I do not understand is the line shown bellow:

```
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
buffer[i] = Serial.read();
```

Will this not just store the first bit from the internal serial buffer into all 8 bits of my variable "buffer"? Shouldn't the code be something more like this?

```
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
buffer[i] = Serial.read()[i];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serial buffer is a queue (google: stack vs queue). The bytes in the queue are dealt with in the order they were received.

Serial.read() takes the first byte from the queue, reads it and deletes it. Next time Serial.read is called the next byte in the queue is available.

Incidentally that is why there is a Serial.peek command. It reads the next byte in the queue but doesn't delete it. You can use this to check the queue for something without purging it

Comment: @djUniversal, I am trying to send to Arduino more than 64 bytes. But it can't read more. I using Serial.read() but the buffer overloaded. If you have any tip please. Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670717/how-do-i-receive-more-that-64-bytes-with-arduino

Answer (score 1):

UART communication is byte-oriented. You never deal with individual bits, that's what the UART hardware is for.

So no, it's correct to move the entire byte.

There's an error in your code, it won't compile. The `buffer` variable should be an array:

```
byte buffer[8];
```

And no, `buffer[0] = Serial.read();`  doesn't somehow smear a single bit into all of your 8 bits, it just copies an 8-bit value, all 8 bits of it, from one place to another. The array indexing operator never does bit-level access, C doesn't work like that.

The checks and loops with 8 are since it wants to receive a single 8-byte message, it's not 8 as in "8 bits".

Comment: But it is inside a for loop, so the first bit of buffer, aka buffer[1], will be assigned all of serial.read(), then  the second bit of buffer, aka buffer[2], will be assigned all of serial.read() etc. This is impossible as buffer[i] is a bit, and serial.read() is a byte.

It's the for loop which confuses me really. Can you please explain this to me?

Thanks.

Comment: @Blue7 `buffer` is declared wrong, I tried to clarify this in my answer.

Comment: It is possible that `byte` (being an Arduino and thus C++ construct) actually provides bit-level access using `[]`, but I don't think so. Anyhow, the intent of the code you linked to is to read 8 **bytes** from the serial port into a memory buffer. There is no need to think about individual bits.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. `Serial.read()` is the same on every iteration of the loop. So all 8 elements are being assigned the same value. on the first iteration of the loop, `buffer[0] = Serial.read()`, and on the second, `buffer[1] = Serial.read()`. `Serial.read()` is the same in both cases. Isn't it? What makes it change?

Comment: I'll try and clarify my question. I originally got my bits and bytes mixed up, but that's clear now. What I'm still confused about is that all 8 elements of `buffer[i]` are being assigned with `Serial.read()`. As `serial.read()` does not change, then all 8 elements of `buffer[i]` are being assigned the same value

Comment: @Blue7 I answered that. Consider an expression like `byte x = 42;`, that does almost exactly the same thing except with the constant value `42` rather than the data read from the UART (`Serial.read()`).

Comment: @Blue7 - *"As `serial.read()` does not change..."* -- That's a faulty assumption. Depending on the UART hardware, this function could access a hardware FIFO or a byte-wide register that would be updated as each character is received over the serial link.  A properly written device driver & API would only return data when fresh bytes are available (i.e. the read blocks until there is new data or the return indicates that no new data is available).